# How can I use jQuery .each() with this form?

Tags: jquery, forms, loops, each

I have a rather large form:

```
<table id="form_table">
    <tr class="table_headers">
        <th>Sources (sorted alphabetically)</th>
        <th>Max $$ Allowed</th>
        <th>You Suggest...</th>
        <th>Warning</th>
        <th>Who Pays This?</th>
        <th>How Much do They Pay?</th>
        <th>How do They Pay?</th>
        <th>Meaning...</th>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td class="label"><p>Borrowed Money (Debt from Bonds)</p></td>
        <td class="max_amount" id="b1"><p>36</p></td>
        <td class="usr_amount"><input type="text" name="c1" class="usrAmts" /></td>
        <td class="warning"><p id="d1"></p></td>
        <td class="paid_by"><p>Property Owners (Property Tax)</p></td>
        <td class="paid_amount"><p id="f1" class="paidAmts"></p></td>
        <td class="paid_how"><p>property tax rate per year</p></td>
        <td class="meaning"><p><span id="h1"></span> per year on a $210,000 house</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label"><p>Business Licenses</p></td>
        <td class="max_amount" id="b2"><p>25</p></td>
        <td class="usr_amount"><input type="text"  name="c2" class="usrAmts" /></td>
        <td class="warning"><p id="d2"></p></td>
        <td class="paid_by"><p>Business Owners' Customers</p></td>
        <td class="paid_amount"><p id="f2" class="paidAmts"></p></td>
        <td class="paid_how"><p>per employee per year</p></td>
        <td class="meaning"><p></p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is use the jQuery `.each()` so that I can alert the user if his input is higher than the value in `<td class="max_amount">` instead of having to write a bunch of if statements.

I guess a good example of pseudo code would be

```
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
   if ($('#usr_input[i]').val() > $('#max_val[i]').val())
      $('span#[i]').text('too high!');
```

or something like that. I don't really know how to put it into words. I apologize if this is poorly-written and can provide more details if asked.

Can I do this with .each() or do I have to write out all the if-statements?

EDIT 1: I revised my HTML (above) and then tried this:

```
$('[id^=usr_input]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() > $('#b'+ i).val()) {
            $('p#d'+ i).text('too high!');
        }
    });
});
```

with no luck.

EDIT 2: Changed to:

```
$('[id^=c]').each(function(i) {
    $(this).on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() > $('#b'+ i).val()) {
            $('p#d'+ i).text('too high!');
        }
    });
});
```

I used `[id^=c]` for the `input` id's

EDIT 3: Added screenshot
[image: Goal]

Comment: You want to use each to find the 'tr' element, and within the each, use .find to pick out the .max_amount and .usr_amount elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$.each` with the selector

```
$('[id^=usr_input]').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).val() > $('#max_val'+ i +']').val())
       $('span#f['+ i +' ]').text('too high!');
});
```

You need to append the value of `i`

That is if you have `inputs` with id in the form of 'max_val1', 'max_val2' and so on

### **UPDATE**

You don't need to use `ID's` here in the first place. You can just iterate over the elements in question using `closest` and get the functionality.

```
// This is where users enter the Amount
// To access value from input you use .val()
// To access value from elements that are not input 
//  you use .text();
$('.usrAmts').on('change', function () {
    // The input that triggered the change
    var $this = $(this),
        // Closest row for input
        // Need this as you want to find the other elements inside 
        // the particular row.
        $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        // Find the p tag inside the max amount
        // need to use text as it is not input
        $max = $row.find('.max_amount p'),
        // warning class that holds error
        $err = $row.find('.warning p');

    if ($(this).val() > parseFloat( $max.text()))  {
        $err.text('too high!');
    } else {
        $err.text('');
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/9kuMu/)**

Comment: Can you tell me what `[id^=...]` means? I've never seen that syntax before.

Comment: That is the id starts with selector.. It will match any elements whose id starts with the value that follows after `=` sign

Comment: It uses the same symbol as regex, but it's not regex.

Comment: Please check original question? I revised and updated my code with Sushanth's suggestion

Comment: @NojoRu.. Where do you have the inputs that have `id` that starts with `usr_input` .. I don't see that in the `HTML
`

Comment: Oh... oops. Does it have to be the `<td>` or can it be `<input>` ?

Comment: Because you are trying to attach a change event. It is supposed to be an input element

Comment: I thought so too. No luck yet. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for the thorough explanation

Comment: @NojoRu.. Glad to have been of help :)

Comment: One more thing: how do I add all those user-inputted values together? I tried creating `var usrTotal` and then doing `usrTotal += $(this).val()` and it didn't work.

Comment: Assign `var usrTotal = 0` .. Otherwise it will try to do `undefined + $(this).val()`  Also better to use `parseFlat` when summing things up...   `usrTotal += parseFloat($(this).val())`

Comment: Okay. What happens with that is that usrTotal is just being overwritten with each subsequent user entry.

Comment: Move the declaration of the `var usrTotal` variable to outside the event handler